# Print A6 on A6 paper

Tags: pdf, printing

I've set a document with a couple of pages in A6:

```
\usepackage[paperheight=4.13in,paperwidth=5.83in, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
```

The pages in the PDF I get as a result are indeed A6 sized.
When I try to print this, though, it always ends up as the A6 page printed onto an A4 page.
Doesn't matter if I try to "print" this to my printer or another PDF.

Maybe a picture helps to show what I mean:

[image: output]

On the right, the PDF produced by TeXShop, and on the left what happens when I try to print it.

Is that a problem my printer and preview have, or can I somehow fix this?

Comment: If you don't give information at your printer about how to print your document it prints the document at the centre of the (A4) paper... it's not a TeX problem, you have only to set properly the printing options (if you have A6 document the best is printing 4 pages for paper)

Comment: The thing is that I want to print to A6 sized index cards, because they are more sturdy than normal paper. And my printer can print on A6 pages, but it somehow doesn't recognize A6 pdfs as inputs. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: A6 is defined using `mm`. By converting `mm` to `in` you unnecessarily add additional rounding issues. Either use `paperwidth=148mm, paperheight=105mm` or just `a6paper, landscape`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the right handling of a not named printer

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic, because I wanted to know if this is something that can be fixed with LaTeX. It can't, it seems, but that doesn't invalidate the question.
I have, as you suggested, decided to just buy thicker paper and cut them out. Thanks for that :)

Comment: I think this is off-topic, being just a printing problem of a file that TeX correctly produces. By the way, `geometry` understands the `a6paper` option, so there's no need to guess the right dimensions.